# How do you get out of the Highwind?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

How do you get out of the Highwind in FF:VII? It is holding me hostage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in the Highwind, talk to Cid to take you into the mini-map so you can fly around.  If you're outside, I believe you just press the O button on a piece of landable flat land.

Comment: Yeah the Highwind can be a bit fussy if you're trying to land on mountain ranges or something like that.

Comment: Um... you talk with the pilot, not with Cid, to go to the mini-map.

Comment: (not really a mini-map either; it's just the map, same size as when you're walking around.)